# On the use of だろう

Tags: grammar, conjugations

「私はすぐには行動しないだろうと侮っていた」

It seems as though だろう is expressing something that is outside of what I've normally seen it used for (e.g. as a substitute for でしょう to mean "probably")

Comment: I'm not a veteran/expert (so I might be wrong), but I'm reasonably sure it should be only one question per post -> two questions (that are unrelated) should be two posts. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post/222741

Comment: It should indeed be two separate questions. And please add in what you think the translations should be and explain why だろう doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, have fixed it I believe!

Answer (score 2):

This だろう does have the function of inference, "I suppose" or "probably will ～". The subject of 侮っていた is 私, but the subject of 行動しないだろう can be either 私 or someone else who has been mentioned in the previous context. と is just a quotative particle.

> すぐには行動しないだろう。
> = すぐには行動しないでしょう。
>
> I think [someone] will not act right away.

> 私はすぐには行動しないだろうと侮っていた。
>
> I had been under the impression that [they/I] (probably) would not act right away.